# Using external libraries in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have compiled a library(GDAL) written in C/C++ with Ruby bindings.

After a ran `make install` it was installed under

```
/Users/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0/
```

There is a directory there called "gdal" with 4 files inside: gdal.so, gdalconst.so, ogr.so, osr.so

What I want now is to use these libraries in my project. The problem is that when I try to referense these files

> require 'gdal/gdal'

I get

> LoadError: no such file to load --
>   gdal/gdal     from
>   :29:in
>   `require'     from
>   <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`
>   require'     from (irb):1    from
>   /Users/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/irb:16:in
>   `'

When I run `ruby -e 'puts $:'` I get following output:

> /Users/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
>
> /Users/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0
>
> /Users/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby
>
> /Users/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
>
> /Users/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0
>
> /Users/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
>
> /Users/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1
>
> /Users/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0

Any ideas why it doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your suggestions. I've finally figured out the problem. It seems like the fact that I was using rvm to manage ruby versions was causing the problem. As soon as I switched to system default(`rvm use system`) everything worked out well.

Answer (score 1):

After `make install` on `OS X` you should have a `.bundle` file in your path `/Users/igor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0`.

If you want to use it then, you just have to `require 'gdal'` and it should fine.

Comment: I don't have .bundle file. Isn't it .so files I should import? When I type require 'gdal' I get the same error message - 'LoadError: no such file to load'

Comment: Could you please upload your `extconf.rb` file?

Comment: How do you build your library? Could you post your `Makefile`?

Comment: here's where I get code from - https://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/ makefile is here as well..

Comment: @igorti looking at those makefiles, the Mac build should have created and installed `.bundle` files, not `.so` files. Did you do something odd like copy an already built tree from a linux box then run `make install` to copy the '.so' files into place?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not using a extconf.rb file to help you generate your makefile.
You might want to read this [tutorial](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2009/12/18/writing-ruby-c-extensions-part-1/) and check [Rice](http://rice.rubyforge.org/) if you want to write a C++ extension. (Ruby is written in C and you need to expose a C API, Rice makes that easier).